# Geometry nodes: Is there a way to specify edge angles in certain increments?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I have some mazes made of simple polygon curves / lines.

My problem is that sometimes these lines are not aligned properly and slightly off-angle. (For example 13.724 degrees)

Is there a way to have all line angles set to a certain increment? For example 5° or 10° steps?

Horizontal / vertical lines should of course be 0° and 90°.

I already tried to use a grid to snap the vertices but it has weird results if the points are not perfectly lining up with the grid dimensions.

I assume I would have to measure the position of 2 points, then measure the angle, compare it with X/Y axis and set the increment from there?

Here is an example.
First image the lines are at random angles.

Second image they are better aligned.

[image]

[image]